# Shorter Term for "Modify & Sign"

Tags: wording

We're working on a web application that has a process of redoing some steps if their resulting document is incorrect (think of a loan application or lease).  We want to give the user an option to re-do it (that is, change some parameters and sign the updated digital document).  So right now, we have a button called "Re-do".

The flow updates the document and collects signatures from all parties involved.

Some feedback is that it can sound like there's a whole lot to do behind a button labeled this way (it sounds more painful than it really is).

**"Modify & Sign..."** is our other option and while it is more descriptive, it's a little long.  **Is there a shorter term?**

The nature of the corrections are user input (e.g., a misspelled name or input of a wrong monetary amount).

Another option I'm considering is **"Modify & Collect Signatures..."** with an intended ellipsis.  Clearer, but not shorter.

Comment: I think your **"Modify & Sign..."** option is just perfect. If there's an error, why on Earth would anyone want to re-do that error? In any case, users will want to **MODIFY**. The benefits of being accurate and descriptive are way bigger than *"it's a little long"* (which is not)

Comment: You might want to change the title of the question - I can see you getting lots of answers for Redo synonyms - when I think actually what you what is a short term for "Modify & Sign".

Comment: @icc97 - that's fair.  Will change it

Answer (score 2):

Looking at ['redo' synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/redo), and given the alternative of 'Modify and Sign', would 'Revise' work?

Edit: Or perhaps would just 'Modify' do? I'd have thought that the 'sign' part would be implicit.

Comment: Yes, we kicked that one around too.   Going to leave this question open to stew for a little...

Comment: For our application, the 'sign' part isn't something we want to gloss over.  So imagine that you have multiple parties signing the document... it can take days depending on when they get to actually doing it.  But in some cases, it can be a few minutes.

Comment: Could the button to submit the edits say 'sign'?

Comment: Well, the final page of the flow contains a box for a digital signature.  The button below it reads "Send to Applicant" or "Send to Manager" depending on the party involved.  I'm looking for help on the first button on the first page of the flow to initiate it all.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of tax software I've used that runs alerts and checks at the end of the return. They prompt you with something like "Review alerts" or "Review and fix warnings". This kind of terminology might work better because:

- It implies the software is helping you by checking your work
- It implies you don't have to do anything (even though the user most likely will make a change, "review warning" doesn't mean they must)
- By calling them "alerts" or "warnings" the user understands that they are small, self-contained changes as opposed to broad sweeping changes or "starting over" as implied by redo.

Even better, you can add a number e.g. "**!** Please review **4** warnings before continuing" so the user knows exactly what to expect.

---

In the case that you don't have any automatic rules to check, I would go even longer (than Modify & Sign) and be more conversational:

*"Please review your document and [click here] to make any changes before signing it"*

Comment: This is a nice concept, but the corrections are not for warnings that our application catches.  They are corrections for user input (say, for example, a name is misspelled or an agreed upon monetary amount is wrong).

Comment: Never say that to a data miner ;-) e.g. hit their name against a corpus of surnames and suggest a correction or compare an amount against a distribution of usual amounts... (totally out of scope of course)